# Power Query Filter date column to yesterday unless today is Monday then filter to Friday

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table in power query that I need to filter to all Yesterday's date unless today is Monday, then I will need to filter to Friday's date. My goal is to show only data with yesterday's date and to not include weekend dates in the mix.

Help Please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on today being Monday or not, yesterday will be either 1 or 3 days back. Determine that, then filter your date column to match

```
 yesterday=  if Date.DayOfWeek(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 1 then Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-3)  else Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1),
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameHere", each [DateColumn] = yesterday)
```